# Suggestions for stepper motor controllers

Tags: arduino, motor, cameras, stepper-driver

I am working on a project where a dslr camera will be rotated on a tripod on 2 axes. I'm definitely using nema 17 motors as those are what I have. The motors will rotate 30 degrees every 5 seconds in normal usage so speed is not a requirement. The weight of the camera is 1170g and I'm using 3d printed parts for the remainder of the mount. I tried running nema 17 stepper motors off a Adafruit Motor Shield V2 but the whole thing overheats (battery, driver, and motor). By the way, the motor will be controlled by an Arduino. I need to find another motor controller to use. I looked on ebay and things like this came up for 20 dollars which seems too good to be true.

My question is what motor driver should I use for this project as I have little experience with them outside of Arduino shields

[image: A motor controller]

Answer (score 0):

A "nema 17 stepper motor ... controlled by an Arduino"
is the same setup used by RepRap 3D printers.
Perhaps one of the stepper drivers on the ["stepper motor driver" page at RepRep](http://reprap.org/wiki/stepper_motor_driver#Stepper_drivers) would be adequate for your project.
That page also has many relatively unbiased comments about each one.

One thing that many people regret: they save a bunch of money buying an extremely low-cost stepper motor controller, and then they are pulling their hair out for weeks because of inadequate documentation.
Stuff with good documentation often costs a little more, but in my opinion is well worth it.

Comment: The drivers used in the reprap are typically polulu or something similar, they require a ramps shield to operate with an arduino. I'm thinking something more contained like the one used here http://makezine.com/video/driving-big-stepper-motors-with-arduino/        Just not a driver for a nema 34 , because that's overkill

Answer (score 0):

I decided on the RAMPS shield from the reprap open hardware initiative. The stepper motors are cheap and the board is too when bought from certain places. The board is expandable and has many possible reuses. Also the pololu drivers are plenty powerful for this project with up to 2.2 amps with proper heat management. They accept ranges up to 45 volts in some cases. Also I have never seen one break on a reprap printer with over 500 prints.